# Can't open Android Studio and get Error of Invalid Log Path

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I got this error in windows 10. **How to solve it?**

Answer (score 0):

1. reboot your computer
2. if above way not working, Just run it as administrator or re-install your IDE